# i made a function what is meant to check if the format of the date of birth the user enters is correct but i can't get it to work

Tags: python, function

```
def checkdob():
    while True:
        dob = input("Date of Birth")
        try:
            dob == datetime.datetime.strptime(dob, '%d-%m-%y')
            break
        except:
            print("Incorrect data format, should be DD-MM-YYYY")
checkdob()
```

Comment: `dob` returns a string (i.e. "07-03-1990"). So you can't just say `if dob:`. You would say `if dob == datetime.datetime.strptime(dob, '%d-%m-%y'):`

Comment: What's not working? Is it giving you any output? If so, add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it works fine. I wonder what you enter as a DOB as an input. Otherwise, it seems to be working fine.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dob = '31-12-99'
>>> if dob:
...   dt_obj = datetime.strptime(dob, '%d-%m-%y')
... 
>>> print dt_obj
1999-12-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: yes but i want to make it into a function though, thanks for the help though

Comment: It is trivial to put above commands into a function, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
def checkdob(dob):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(dob, '%d-%m-%Y')
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect data format, should be DD-MM-YYYY")
        return None


while not checkdob(input("Date of Birth")):
    pass
```